# Factorial power divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Under what conditions is \begin{equation*}\frac{\left(n^2-1\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^{n}}\end{equation*} an integer? (It turns out, apparently, that the answer is "precisely when $n$ is non-prime and $\neq 4$". I am interested in whether there is a straightforward proof of this.)

Comment: Hmm...  $\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$ would be a multinomial coefficient, so that would be an integer.  Not sure if you could use that somehow.

Comment: You can do it using Legendre's formula but it might get annoying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite:

$$\begin{align}\frac {(n^2-1)!}{(n!)^n} &= \frac{(n^2-1)!}{(n^2-n)!n!}\frac {(n^2-n)!}{(n!)^{n-1}} \\&= \frac1n\frac{(n^2-1)!}{(n^2-n)!(n-1)!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac {(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots(kn+n)}{n!}\\& = \frac1n\binom{n^2-1}{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac {(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots(kn+n-1)}{(n-1)!}\frac {kn+n}{n}\\& = \frac1n\binom{n^2-1}{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom {n(k+1)-1}{n-1}(k+1)\end{align}$$

Since all the binomial coefficients are integers, the problem reduces to finding when:

$$\frac1n\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}(k+1) = \frac{(n-1)!}n \in \mathbb Z$$

A proof of the condition $n$ not prime and $n\ne 4$ is given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Divisibility_of_n-1_Factorial_by_Composite_n). (Should I outline it instead? It is actually pretty obvious)

The proof in the link did not consider the case where $n$ is prime, but that case is obvious as well, since all of $1 \le k \le n-1$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: "The problem reduces to finding when" - how do you justify that? It's still possible than a non-integer times a bunch of integers can be an integer, if the non-integer is rational with a suitable denominator.

Comment: You're right. In that case this proof only gives "condition $\implies \in \mathbb Z$". Then we just need to show "prime or $4 \implies \notin \mathbb Z$", which is not very hard if you consider the power of $n$ in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thanks!